# Date/Time Fields in Processes

Tags: apex, process-builder, process

I'm told its possible for me to display a date field on a page layout that will then change to a date/time field in my process.

Example: User puts in a new starter starting date on the record but not specifying a time, there is a process that will use an invocable method with a time delay of an hour after the start date however this is causing flow errors as it doesn't know what time to start from.

I'm told its possible to keep this function as is but in the process, you can change the datatype to a date/time field, is this true?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcnyN.png - The flow where I would like it to change to a date field, currently it's looking for a time to start but errors as the time isn't specified

Comment: Hi Harry, could you please update your question to actually ask a question and perhaps give some more concrete information about your issue - detail about the object schema and the process definition perhaps?

Comment: If using only PB, you will need two fields on the object, one of Date, one of Datetime and the first decision block sets the Datetime field using a formula expression, then goes to the next block and uses the Datetime field as input to the invocable